# Cucumber Command Line

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber, command-line-arguments

I am trying to run different tests by making a cucumber command line call using this code

```
public class RunTest {
    public RunTest(String test){
        System.out.println("you found me");        System.setProperty("protocol","https");
        String[] argv = {"-p", "json:cucumber-report.json", "-g", "Otto.CatalogTests", "classes/"+ test +".feature"};
        main(argv);
    }
}
```

I however get this error messsage:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.cucumber.messages.Messages$Meta$Builder.setProtocolVersion(Messages.java:6186)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.emitMeta(CucumberExecutionContext.java:59)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.startTestRun(CucumberExecutionContext.java:47)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:71)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:76)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:33)
        at Otto.CommandLine.RunTest.<init>(RunTest.java:16)
        at Otto.CommandLine.ArgumentHandler.executeArguments(ArgumentHandler.java:63)
        at Otto.CommandLine.ArgumentHandler.<init>(ArgumentHandler.java:28)
        at Otto.CommandLine.Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

when you click on this link: Messages.java:6186 you see this code:

```
public Messages.Meta.Builder setProtocolVersion(String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    } else {
        this.protocolVersion_ = value;
        this.onChanged();
        return this;
    }
}
```

it would appear I am not setting my protocol version how could I go about doing this?

I tried `System.setProperty("protocol","https");`but that did not work nor do i know what protocol is best practice.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that you are using Cucumber `v6.0.0-RC2`. And it would also appear that you are shading Cucumber into your project. In that case you'll have to add an implementation and specification version to your manifest file. If you happen to be using maven you can do that with with `maven-jar-plugin`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Gradle should have its own equivalent.